# Swift - How to make a view controller scrollable?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller with some elements in it.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    // ......
}
```

This is what I want:
[example of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLhmE.gif)

This is what my app looks like:

[image: my app]

I want to make the two elements (an imageView and a button) to be vertically scrollable like the example.

What should I do? I have checked **UIScrollView**, but still don't know how to do it. Can you show me some code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an UI Component inside UIKit called `UIScrollView`. This Component can be used to achieve the **Scrolling Behaviour** you probably aim for.

> Check out the official Documentation by Apple
> [UIScrollView | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview)

> Another great resource for getting started with UIScrollViews is this one.
> [UIScrollView Tutorial: Getting Started](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5758454-uiscrollview-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have checked UIScrollView, but still doesn't know how to do it. Can you show me some code?

Comment: @Victor you can create the whole scrolling behaviour directly in your Storyboard File using AutoLayout. Just spend an hour or so checking out this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5758454-uiscrollview-tutorial-getting-started I learned it there and afterwards you know everything about ScrollViews Page Navigation and so on.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I still don't know exactally how to do it in my view controller.

Comment: @Victor, that's not a place where you expect to get just code. You've been guided to check out the `ScrollView` by @christopher , and then if you are having any problem in using it, post it here or ask a new question.

Comment: @Coder Ok I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is programmatically create an `UIScrollView` in your `UIViewController`.

To control the *scrollability* you can set the ScrollView `contentSize` property. In the following sample we match `contentSize.width` with `self.view.frame.size.width` to prevent horizontal scroll.

So, to achieve your goal, you must add your components inside the scrollView using `scrollView.addSubview`

This is a simple sample of a UIScrollView with a red UIView inside:

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scroll = UIScrollView()
        scroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scroll.delegate = self
        scroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 1000)
        return scroll
    }()
    
    lazy var redView:UIView = {
        let redview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        redview.backgroundColor = .red
        return redview
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(redView)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        let layout = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layout.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layout.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layout.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layout.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    
}
```